# How does Zurb Foundation Switch control work

Tags: zurb-foundation

I recently started using Zurb Foundation 4 for an Asp MVC website and I don't quite understand how the switch control is supposed to work. The docs don't say much http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/switch.html

```
<div class="switch">
  <input id="x" name="switch-x" type="radio" checked>
  <label for="x" onclick="">Off</label>

  <input id="x1" name="switch-x" type="radio">
  <label for="x1" onclick="">On</label>

  <span></span>
</div>
```

I'm using this example code, when I click on the switch, there is no change in the html. I figured the "checked" attribute would go on the second input, but this is not the case.

- How can I detect which radio button has been clicked ?

When I POST the form, the "switch-x" variable contains the value "on" no matter what position the switch is in.

I tried adding an onclick event on the label, but it's not getting fired as something seems to be overlapping the label.

I'm using foundation's javascript, I don't have any errors on the page.

I'm definitely missing something... Any ideas ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I detect which radio button has been clicked ?

You have an `id` for each of your radio inputs so you can use them:

```
$('input[name=switch-x]:checked').attr('id');
```

That will give you either `x` or `x1`. Now it depends on how you will use it. But if you will be passing it as a boolean value, which I think you would, then you can simply do a:

```
var isOn = $('input[name=switch-x]:checked').attr('id') == 'x1';
```

or just simply

```
var isOn = $('#x1').is(':checked');
```

[See it in action here](http://jsfiddle.net/KYPh5/)

Comment: If you follow the link to the documentation, there is a working example. You will see that the checked attribute is not modified when the switch is clicked. So if I use your method, I will always get the same value even though the switch has changed position.

Comment: Have you tried it? It works, [see it in action here](http://jsfiddle.net/KYPh5/).

Comment: Ok so now I just feel stupid. I was not seeing the checked attribute being changed in the html (using firebug) so I assumed nothing was happening. Cheers

Comment: Ah, does if you give the radio buttons values! Duh.

Answer (score 5):

> When I POST the form, the "switch-x" variable contains the value "on" no matter what position the switch is in.

You need to add a value in your input fields to have the $_POST["switch-x"] value, as :

```
<div class="switch">
  <input id="x" name="switch-x" type="radio" value="0" checked>
  <label for="x" onclick="">Off</label>

  <input id="x1" name="switch-x" type="radio" value="1">
  <label for="x1" onclick="">On</label>

  <span></span>
</div>
```